# Does it make a difference (speed-wise) if i pick an object by index or via „find“ from an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The title pretty much descripes it.
I got an array of days, sorted by the date. So the 1th of the month would be month[0].

When i pick these days in a loop, would it be faster to do this by

`month.find(day => day.date === date)`

Or

`month[date-1]`

Thank you for help  :)

Answer (score 1):

It does make a difference. When you use a direct index to look up the associated item, the computational complexity is `O(1)` - the engine just needs to look at the item at that single index and it finds it. But when you use `.find`, you go through every element of the array and call the callback on each one, only stopping once the found object passes the test.

That said, you'd only *notice* a difference if you were doing this sort of thing with a huge array and/or in a very tight loop. The difference will be utterly imperceptible most of the time.